# Python: How to assign Python function to HTML button using Django

Tags: python, html, django

Python 3.8.5
Django 3.1.2

I created a Django Project. I have an HTML page created with a button.
I need to assign the following urlpattern to that HTML button...

```
path('', views.output, name='output'),
```

That URLpattern is linked to a function called 'output' which runs successfully on it's own.
I'm using the following HTML code to assign that function to my HTML button...

```
<button onclick="Location.href='{% url 'output' %}'"> Enter </button>
```

This does not work. I cannot get this button to run my function.
Does anyone know how to assign this function successfully?
Here is my code in my urls.py file...

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.output, name='output'),
]
```

Comment: It is `location.href`, not `Location.href`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a button using a tags with bootstrap. It will be like this

```
<a href="{% url 'output'%}" class="btn btn-primary">Enter</a>
```

If you were not using bootstrap you can style it.

**HTML**

```
 <a href="{% url 'output'%}" class="button">Enter</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.button {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;

text-decoration: none;
color: initial;}
```